# How to get image from a custom listView enclosed within relative layout

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom listview with a text and imageview enclosed in relative layout. I want to get the information of the imageview present inside custom listview. I have tried `getItemAtPosition(position)` but that is not working.

Is there any way to get the imageView from custom listview?

Comment: How you are setting the image view picture? using array to store the drawables ids? or like else what? provide minimum code for it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I feel compelled to ask if you are threatening to defeat the purpose of the adapter pattern by making your view aware of the data being displayed? If so, you may want to just query the adapter for the object being bound by the view and work from that rather than querying the view itself.

Otherwise, there is an OnItemSelected and OnItemClicked listeners that you can override and set on the list view. Both of these return the view being clicked at which point you can use the method findViewById to get the view you want. If you want a random child, well, it gets a bit more difficult. I would guess you could iterate over the children of the listview but, at that point, I really think you should consider if this is the best route to accomplish what you want.

My recommendation would be to make sure your adapter can give you the information you need so that you don't have to squirrel it away in the views built by the adapter.